# Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type [Int] sum of square

Tags: haskell

```
fsomaq = x

x = sum (takeWhile (<x) [m | m <- [n*n | n <- [1..]]])
```

What Im trying to do here is get a limit `x` and then square every number and then sum all this.

Any idea ? error message:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’ with actual type ‘Integer’ •

 The function ‘fsomaq’ is applied to one argument, but its type ‘Integer’ has none In the expression: fsomaq 10 In an equation for ‘it’: it = fsomaq 10 • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at :16:1)
```

Comment: x = sum ( takeWhile (<x) [m | m <- [n*n | n <- [1..]]])

Comment: This does not makes much sense. You want the sum of elements that are less than the sum of these elements...

Comment: sorry Im new in this

Comment: What I want here is a limit x, then I want the sum of the square of all these numbers, example:
x = 5 
(1,2,3,4,5) - (1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4 + 5*5) = show this result

Comment: Your example should resolve like `sum . takeWhile (<x) $ [n*n | n <- [1..]]` where `x` is resembles limit for the squares.

Comment: Note that `[ m | m <- someList ]` is a rather complex way of writing `someList`.

Comment: You are trying to do too much in a single line of code. I suggest you assign each piece to its own variable in order to reason about the solution more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to define a function that takes as input a number, and returns the sum of squares from 1 up to (and including) that number. You can write such function with:

```
fsomaq :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a
fsomaq x = sum [n*n | n <- [1..x] ]
```

So we here define a function `fsomaq` that takes as input a parameter `x`, the outcome is then `sum [ n*n | n <- [1..x] ]` so we write a *list comprehension* to produce a list of squares with `n` ranging from `1` to (and including `x`), and we emit squares (`n*n`). We then calculate the sum of that list.

By defining the signature as `(Num a, Enum a) => a -> a`, we can use any type of number that is enumerable.

For example:

```
Prelude> fsomaq 0
0
Prelude> fsomaq 1
1
Prelude> fsomaq 2
5
Prelude> fsomaq 4
30
Prelude> fsomaq 8
204
Prelude> fsomaq 1425
965562425
```

Comment: YEESS! I didn't need the takeWhile thing, forgot about the [1..x]
Thank you, worked great here!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too much in a single line. I suggest that you break it apart to reason about the solution more clearly. For example start with:

```
list = [1..]
squares = [n*n | n <- list]
```

Now what do you wan to do with the list of squares? Do you want ones smaller than a given value? Then do something like:

```
squaresLessThanX x = takeWhile (<x) squares
```

Now we want to sum these squares:

```
sumSquaresLessThanX x = sum $ squaresLessThanX x
```

Notice how much easier this is to read than the oneliner that you are attempting. We also avoided many of the errors that you made, including mismatched brackets and reusing variable names incorrectly.

Comment: thank you, but now I have a different problem,
I want to multiply matrix NxN
So far I got 
main = do
    putStrLn "Digite 'matriz' seguido do tamanho (100,1000,2000)"
    matriz :: Int -> [[(Int, Int)]]
    matriz let n = map (\x -> map (\y -> (x, y)) [1..n]) [1..n]

But Im having problems with the putStrLn , the problem is, input a value n (100,1000,2000) then I have to calculate the matrix times matrix e.g 100x100

Comment: @Pedro Follow the same technique I show here. Break the problem into very small pieces. When you have tried some things post a new question for each issue.